# What is the best solution to handle multiple users assigned same session ID at once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, authentication

My asp .net mvc3 web application is facing issue which is application assigning same session id to multiple user login (using different credentials) that use same browser. After a user log-in using some credentials, then the next time he attempts to login with a different credential using another window in the same browser, I want the user to be redirected to the home page of first login just like in facebook. How can I achieve this? I thought of storing session Id of each user in DB and then check if the session ID is already in when a login attempt is made. But this seem to hit application performance. Can anyone tell me what is the best approach to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the property

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

In your login form.  If the user is `IsAuthenticated` then redirect them to their homepage instead of the displaying/processing the login form.

Comment: No. session id are being generated by browser. All users trying to login using same browser shares a common session ID . Also session ends once user logs out but session ID is getting reused

Comment: Bravo!! This is exactly what I needed. Its working fine for me.